# How to make English the default language (android)

Tags: android, speech-recognition

My app use Speech To Text recognition, and if I change the device language my app doesn't work correctly. I want to make English language by default in my app. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Locale myLocale;
 myLocale = new Locale("en");
 Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
 android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
 config.locale = myLocale;
 getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Try making new folder values-en, make strings.xml in it and copy your english strings in the new strings file

Comment: No it still doesn't work for, it works for language which was selected in a system.

Comment: try to change  myLocale = new Locale("en"); with this line  myLocale = new Locale("en", "US");

Comment: I tryed it already, also I tryed "English (US)", "en_US" but until I change the system language in English it doesn't work.